# Magento 2 get media url in KO's template file

Tags: magento2

I want to get media url like abc.com/store/pub/media/ (site url like abc.com/store .) in My ko template(.html) file.

we can use `require.toUrl('');` for static view file. same way i want to get media view file

Answer (score 0):

I used a dirty code to get the media URL in any HTML file.
You can use a better way if you want but this is a simple and dirty solution :)

Add following code to

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/absolute_footer.phtml

```
...
...

<script>
    window.getMediaUrl = "<?= $block->getBaseUrl() . 'pub/media/' ?>";
</script>
```

Now you can get media URL in any HTML file as given below

```
<span data-bind="text: window.getMediaUrl" ></span>
```

Comment: this is will not work on production mode